# User not associated with SQL Connection Error

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2005, authentication

I am getting the error below, that the user is not associated with a trusted SQL server connection. It would look like I am being logged in using my windows credentials (which is a local account). I wrote the application on a domain computer and moved it to my laptop for testing. The laptop is not on the domain, my web.config is listed below. I can login into SQL server with the account I am using and have full access to the database. The server is setup for mixed authentication. I am running Windows 7 with iis 7.5 debugging it in Visual Studio 2010. Anyone have any ideas on what is going in?

Web.config

```
<add name="MediaTrackerConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=myserver.full.domain.com;Initial Catalog=MediaTracker;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

In my page I have:

```
           mediaConnection = new SqlConnection("user id=DOMAIN\user;" +
                      "password=XXXXXX;server=myserver.full.domain.com;" +
                      "initial catalog=MediaTracker; " +
                      "connection timeout=30");
```

Error I am getting:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Login failed for user ''. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user ''. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user ''. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +5064474
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() +234
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +2275
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK) +35
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection owningObject) +183
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout) +239
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +195
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +232
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection) +185
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options) +33
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject) +524
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject) +66
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject) +479
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) +108
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +126
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +125
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +123
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +319
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable) +92
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments) +1618
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataList.GetData() +56
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataList.CreateControlHierarchy(Boolean useDataSource) +177
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataList.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e) +64
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataList.DataBind() +55
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataList.EnsureDataBound() +78
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataList.CreateChildControls() +73
   System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +102
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +42
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2496
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have full access to the SQL Server instance running on your computer, but you may need to map your account to interface with the database from the application.

Right click on the database and go to properties. Go to "User Mappings," and assign the appropriate priveleges for your user account.

**EDIT**

It sounds like you might have Windows Authentication mode enabled, in which case your application is probably trying to connect to the database with the NETWORK SERVICE account. Remove the credentials from your connection string and give the NETWORK SERVICE account permissions to acccess the database. Otherwise, make sure mixed-mode authentication is enabled and use the `sa` account to access the database.

Comment: I made sure that the user has the mappings for that database, I have also tried my domain account as the user and both fail. My Domain account is owner of every database. So I am still stuck.

Comment: Is the application running in IIS or are you using Cassini?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2008/05/03/understanding-the-error-message-login-failed-for-user-the-user-is-not-associated-with-a-trusted-sql-server-connection.aspx) are a few points you'll want to take a look at.  Just to repeat what the article says:

1. If this error message occurs every time in an application using Windows Authentication, and the client and the SQL Server instance are on separate machines, then ensure that the account which is being used to access SQL Server is a domain account.  If the account being used is a local account on the client machine, then this error message will occur because the SQL Server machine and the Domain Controller cannot recognize a local account on a different machine.
2. this error message can appear if the user logging in is a domain account from a different, untrusted domain from the SQL Server’s domain.
3. This error message can appear immediately after a password change for the user account attempting to login.
4. If this error message only appears sporadically in an application using Windows Authentication, it may result because the SQL Server cannot contact the Domain Controller to validate the user.
5. This error message can appear consistently for local connections using trusted authentication, when SQL Server’s SPN is not interpreted by SSPI as belonging to the local machine.  This can be caused either by a misconfiguration of DNS, or by a machine having multiple names.

Comment: I have tried using both SQL and windows authentication and this still happens. So i'm not sure what is going on.